# Tag merge / synonym request: [interface] -> [interfaces]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Could we merge [interface](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface) questions (41 total) into [interfaces](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interfaces) (10 total), and make them synonyms?

<sub>Side note given the number of questions, I'd bet 4:1 that "interface" makes better master tag. But since [the usual rule is to have the plural as the tag](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/tag-merge-synonym-request-interfaces-interface/3493#comment9388_3492), I wouldn't mind it done the other way.</sub>

Comment: The usual rule is to have the plural as the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've suggested the synonym but with [interfaces](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interfaces) as the master (as it's more usual to have the plural as the tag).

I'll wait a little while to get some more feedback before finalising it.

Comment: thanks! I tried to vote up but discovered that I am [not strong enough](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/does-the-tag-synonym-suggestion-system-work "MSO discussion: 'Does the tag synonym suggestion system work?'") for that